# Getting override error while setting up react-native-push-notification

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I am getting override error when I set package in MainApplication.java. I am getting this error that i should use canOverrideExistingModule=true but i don't know how to set that up.

**NOTE:** I don't need firebase. I just need to setup local and scheduled notifications.

[image]

react-native: '0.70.5'
react-native-push-notification: "^8.1.1",

I have tried removing package from MainApplication.java but that doesn't work either.